# Rotate video object in actionscript 2.0

Tags: flash, video, actionscript-2

I have Video player in adobe flash with actionscript 2.0. I got video from server side which has angle of -90 degree. 
Now i want to rotate video to 90 degree which property is have to use for that.

I tried following:

```
myVideoPlayer.rotation = 90;
```

But, did not get success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate an object on AS2, we use [`object._rotation`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7e5d.html) ( **rotation** with an **underscore** ), so your code should be :

```
myVideoPlayer._rotation = 90;
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Yes you right +1 for that but now it's quality become low. some part of video are cut.

Comment: @ketan Of course, personally, I don't recommend this method to play your video, but I just tried to answer your question. You have to repositionate and resize your video player. For the quality, try `video_player.smoothing = true; `.